# Transferring sockets between threads.?

Tags: c#, multithreading, sockets

I'm trying to build this server that receives connections on a socket, authenticates the user and then "sends" the socket to the class of the user that matches it(with the info given in the authentication), to be added to a thread pool (of the multiple devices of that client) to be processed (exchanging information, updating things elsewhere, etc..).

*I chose to do it this way because I don't want to be sending requests to the server 24/7, just keep a lightweight thread open for each device, communicating with it in real time.*

Now, all I've seen so far that might do something like this is Socket.DuplicateAndClose, but that works for processes, not threads.

So is anyone aware of any way to do this, or should I take a different approach?
Thank you.

EDIT:
It seemed that there was some confusion, what I meant was, move it to another Socket inside another class, then the threads open on that class will process it. If I accept the connection to authenticate it, that socket then is having that connection, beforehand I couldn't have known to accept it with the specific socket in the specific class because I didn't know where it came from, and now, I have a thread I can't do anything with because I can't tell that class to use this thread, because if I do and use it in a thread of that class, the next socket I use to accept the connection will be the one that's occupied by that same class. I could use a huge array to store accepted sockets and tell classes that that socket number was theirs, but that would not only be limited but a bunch of loose sockets as well, which would work but would be neither optimized or organized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no restriction on which threads access a given socket.

Any thread can perform operations on any socket (providing the thread's process has an open handle to that thread).

Performing multiple IO operations of the same type (eg. two reads) concurrently on one socket is likely to lead to confusion – you cannot control which will get the next data, and it could then complete second. But any form of explicit or implicit concurrence control can be used to avoid that.

(The same applies to other kernel objects like files, named pipes, shared memory sections, semaphores, …. The only thing that is restricted is only the thread holding a mutex or critical section can release it.)

Comment: Yes, that does make sense, and I'm so sorry if I didn't ask my question correctly, I will edit,as a comment it was too big.

Comment: Actually you did answer the question and I don't see the point on talking about a different one, I'm marking it as solved and opening one with the right question.

Comment: @TrisT A `Socket` field in a type is just reference to the object. You can reassign it (and multiple references to the same object is also fine). (Caveat: unless the field is `readonly` but that's a type definition issue and nothing to do with the referent).